# How do I prove that my ISP is violating basic principles of Net Neutrality?

Tags: dns, internet, isp

There are two major e-commerce websites in my country say "abc.com" & "xyz.com". I live in a locality where there are around 50+ broadband users of this ISP. So what happens is whenever I try to load "abc.com" it loads in milliseconds but when I try to open "xyz.com" it takes ages.
I have tried following things already:

1. Tried all sorts of DNS changes like from google, open dns, isp's dns auto dns, etc.
2. Did same test on around 15+ computers in my locality.
3. If I open the same two websites on my phone which is from another ISP, both the websites take around same time to open up.

So isn't it the violation of basic principles of Net Neutrality? If yes, then how should I prove it? We have a Govt. agency which controls all the ISPs and I can complain to them.

Comment: That's a pretty strong statement. Maybe their route to that host is just high latency, and it's just a technical problem that they're unaware of?

Comment: What should I do then?

Comment: Make them aware of it; they may decide to further investigate it, and figure out what is causing the issue. Ask them for a case number, so that you can track their progress.

Comment: Suppose that they are doing it intentionally, How do I prove that?

Comment: You're going to need to amass data that proves that the site loads much faster from many other locations. Then you're going to need to provide documentation that you spent a lot of time trying to work with the ISP to resolve the issue, and that they were completely uninterested in resolving the problem. Even then, it could easily be dismissed as "poor customer service", not intentional degradation of speeds for specific traffic. I'm pretty sure that the ISP is going to be given the benefit of the doubt unless you can get them to document that the traffic to that site has specific limits.

Comment: Can I get into some legal trouble for making such claims like a multi million case of defamation?

Comment: We can't offer legal advice, especially if we don't know what country you're in... Plus, most of us aren't lawyers

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've eliminated every other possibility, purchase a subscription to an anonymizing VPN service and then try accessing both sites with the VPN active.  Ensure that DNS traffic travels over the VPN as well.  In this case, the ISP cannot see your traffic, and if access times to both sites are the same, your ISP may indeed be doing some traffic engineering based on domain name.

You need to ensure that you are requesting the same amount of data from xyz.com as abc.com - perhaps xyz.com's desktop site is laden with slow Flash ads and their mobile site is not?  So again, make sure you've really eliminated every other possibility.

This is hardly enough proof of a violation net neutrality, because there are legitimate reasons for such traffic engineering (i.e. mitigating DDOS from that network, etc.), and routing issues can cause similar issues.  It may garner some attention (good or bad) if you present it to your ISP, though.

Comment: Or use Tunnel Bear for free to anonymize your browsing.

Comment: I tried tunnel bear and the loading times still vary, not too much but they do, like abc.com open up 5-10 seconds before xyz.com.